# Multikey Indexes with Bounds mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to figure out multikey index's with bounds with an example I have.

```
s1:PRIMARY> db.inventory.find();
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABCx", "ratings" : [ 4, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "ABC", "ratings" : [ 2, 9 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "XYZ", "ratings" : [ 4, 3 ] }
```

I do a find like this

```
s1:PRIMARY> db.inventory.find( { ratings: { $gte: 5 ,$lte:8} } );
```

output :

`{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "ABC", "ratings" : [ 2, 9 ] }`

As per the documentation here and I quote (quote contains a different example than mine)

> The query searches the ratings array for at least one element greater
>   than or equal to 3 and at least one element less than or equal to 6.
>   Because a single element does not need to meet both criteria, MongoDB
>   does not intersect the bounds and uses either [ [ 3, Infinity ] ] or [
>   [ -Infinity, 6 ] ]. MongoDB makes no guarantee as to which of these
>   two bounds it chooses.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/multikey-index-bounds/

based on this documentation, i should have all 3 rows as my output instead of just one row.

Can someone clarify how does this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `$gte` and `$lte` must match at least one element within the document's `result` array in the `.find()` method. So, for `$gte: 5, $lte: 8`:

- `_id: 2` has `[ 4, 3 ]` => `$lte: 8` matches either element, but `$gte: 5` cannot match either `3` or `4`, so not returned;
- `_id: 3` has `[ 2, 9 ]` =>  `$lte: 8` matches `2` and `$gte: 5` matches `9`, so it is returned;
- `_id: 4` has `[ 4, 3 ]` => same as `_id: 2`.

Therefore, it makes sense that only document with `_id: 3` is returned. Add an element that is `$gte: 5` to `_id: 2` or `_id: 4` document's `result` array, and it'll match that document!